# VSCode Debugger for Chrome is unable to verify breakpoints with fresh Angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to get the Debugger for Chrome to work with Angular projects but I'm having no luck after following these instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial#_debugging-angular

I've created a fresh angular (8.1.1) project with `ng new testdebug` and opened the created folder in VSCode (1.36.1). After that I've added a launch configuration for Chrome and changed the port to 4200.

[image]

When I now start my app with `npm start` and launch the debugger with `F5` the browser opens, everthing seems to work and I even get the `console.log` output in VSCode.

But whatever I do my breakpoints always stay greyed out with the message `Unverified Breakpoint`.

[image]

I've searched around quite a bit about this issue but most people just messed up to set the correct folder for `webRoot`. But in my case the setup is exactly as described in the offical VSCode instructions and I don't have a more complex nested structure.

What else could it be? Can I somehow find out why the Debugger for Chrome isn't able to verify my breakpoints?